# Is there any method for getting random context every time page reloads?

Tags: python

The goal is to make `index.html` get random context when we reload page. I don't know how to search for this. I've tried converting QuerySet to json for using it in script tag of `index.html`.

models.objects.ordered_by('?').first()

#### views.py

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    model = models.Meal
    recommended_meal = models.Meal.objects.ordered_by('?').first()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["recommended_meal"] = self.context
        return context
```

#### index.html

This codes exist between `{%block%}~{%endblock%}`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="picture_food">
      <a href="%url  "> <img src="{{recommended_meal.meal_photo.url}}" class = "img-rounded"></a>
      <h1>{{recommended_meal.meal_name}}</h1>
      <ul>
        <p>{{recommended_meal.restaurant_name}}</p>
        <p>{{recommended_meal.price_range}}</p>
        <p>{{recommended_meal.satisfaction}}</p>
      </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

When I reload my `index.html` page, I got the same result, but when the server restarts it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely should be `context["recommended_meal"] = self.recommended_meal`?

I think the problem is that you are resolving `recommended_meal` down to a single fixed object with `.first()` at the time the class is defined. I'd suggest you try

```
context["recommended_meal"] = models.Meal.objects.ordered_by('?').first()
```

in the `get_context_data` method.

Comment: PS best to add django tag on django-related posts